# jQuery: How to make Progress Bar animate from one to another color

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jquery-animate, progress-bar

I like to change barColor to have diferent colors on start and end.

```
var EasyPieChart = function(el, opts) {
    var defaultOptions = {
        barColor: '#FFEA82',
        trackColor: '#e1e1e3',
        scaleColor: '#e1e1e3',
        scaleLength: 0,
        lineCap: 'round',
        lineWidth: 15,
        size: 152,
        rotate: 0,
        animate: 1000,
        easing: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
```

I tried something like this but didn't work.

```
from: {barColor: '#FFEA82', a:0},
to: {barColor: '#ED6A5A', a:1},
```

I need something like this

[image: I need something like this]

Comment: Try somehting like: if progress > 25%: update color etc.

Answer (score 0):

This works, and it's also mentioned in their GitHub page https://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/  - "You can also pass a function that accepts the current percentage as a value to return a dynamically generated color"

```js
barColor: function(percent){
    if(percent<=60)
   return "#ffe500";
    else
   return "#ff7f50";
   },
trackColor: '#e1e1e3',
```